# Regression on a timeseries signal using RNN, works well but is delayed by 1 time point

Tags: regression, recurrent-neural-network

I implemented my own NN framework and did a regression on a small dataset that follows pretty good the target only is delayed forward, by 1 time point.
This is how the validation data looks:
[image]

The curios thing is that the training data looks the same:

[image]

Although the prediction has almost the same shape as the target signal, the 1 time point difference creates a significant difference between the 2 signals.

Did anyone encountered this kind of problem and know how to solve it ? 
For other datasets the regression works very well, also on timeseries, also for classification, using my NN framework. It could be a bug, but why does it work very well on MNIST10 ? and other timeseries datasets ?

I used a classic RNN, not a LTSM.
Input data is a time lagged input from (t, t-1, ....., t-12).
Input data was normalized in [0,1], then sent to hidden layer 1 activated with tanh, then to hidden layer 2 activated with tanh, and then to error layer activated with sigmoid(tried also linear, same thing). Hidden layers each have a context layer that stores the activation of the hidden layer at the previous time t-1 to feed it at time t to the hidden layer.

I sent batches of 128 sequences of length 10,13,30,40 and other. The train dataset has about 2950 time points, and the val dataset has 155 time points.

The accuracy is:
TRAIN Root mean squared error: 0.038273 
TRAIN Correlation coefficient: 0.974084 
VAL Root mean squared error: 0.054285 
VAL Correlation coefficient: 0.861191

Does anyone know how this problem can be solved using RNNs ? I am not interested in using other statistical models or Google frameworks.

Many thanks,
Viorel

Comment: I think I understand the problem as explained here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197494/delay-issue-in-time-series-prediction

Comment: I also simulated a random walk starting from a signal S and created R = S + small noise and indeed R follows very wel S but with a 1 time delay.
Ok, I now understand the problem, my RNN takes any sequence and outputs the last time point in the sequence + some noise.

Comment: But why does this happen ? All I see that is strange, is that the trained weights from the context layer to the hidden layer are very small, in interval [-0.01, 0.01] when the other trained weights stay in [-0.5, 0.5]. Maybe this is the cause ?

Comment: I sort of fixed this.
I filtered the signal with a gaussian, and the neural net successfully predicted the smoothed signal. But then I have to add back the noise to the prediction.

Answer (score 4):

This is not surprising and happens often with much simpler linear time series models. Imagine you have a martingale process (a process that basically moves randomly in every step). The optimal forecast is whatever value you had in the previous period.

What I think your graph is telling you is that, according to your model, its best forecast is whatever it saw last.